# Java EE Project in Tomcat return always 404

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a project written in Java EE, using Itellij Idea with tomcat 7 it always returns 404 for any url.

web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhQgg.png)

Comment: Can you share other configuration files to observe project more clearly?

Comment: Do you have any servlets or JSPs? Exactly what is in your project?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that out? The project has jsp files in web folder with WEB-INF

Comment: Well, your web.xml doesn't contain anything. You need to define a servlet for the container to forward calls to.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjjkc/index.html

Comment: @JohnDeerech, is this all what your web.xml contains?

Comment: Yes, that's all the web.xml has

Comment: All the urls mapping are done with Controllers

Comment: Do you have a `WebInitializer` it's the replacement of web.xm in Servlet 3.0

Comment: @MouadELFakir No WebInitializer in the project.

Comment: Actually there are two types of configurations, **Annotation config** : it requires a WebInitializer which is the replacement of web.xml, or **XML config** : which requires the web.xml, since your `web.xml` is empty you have to add a `WebInitializer` to the project.

Comment: @MouadELFakir understood, do you have a example?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/spring-mvc-without-web-xml-using-webapplicationinitializer/

Comment: @MouadELFakir I don't think its using spring. I attached the project structure.

Comment: JavaEE way would be using `@WebServlet` annotation - see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html. Also, since you never mentioned: did that project ever work? Or does it work when you do something differently (not through Intellij, not in tomcat)?

Comment: @Deltharis Who gave it to me said it works out of the box